# Queue .Net Code Behind Execution

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I am working on a .Net application which has a blank .aspx page which links to a code-behind (.aspx.cs) sheet. It is called by JavaScript functions from many places which call the page with query-string parameters.

Dependent on the parameters - the page runs 2 families of stored procedures. One family creates records - the other updates records. Any SQL errors are then e-mailed over to me.

There is an error that I suspect is due to the code being executed twice in rapid succession - I receive a unique primary key constraint error. It seems that the page is being called a second time before the INSERT has taken place. This unfortunately is causing data-loss.

My question is...

How do I "Lock" or "Queue" aspx.cs page executions/requests to ensure that one "instance" or "thread" of the page completes before another may be fired?

Comment: I would recommend fixing your SQL statements so that this is not possible rather than queueing your executions into the page.  If you could post the code for your inserts we may be abel to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the invoking of the process from the execution of the process.

Basically you would add a table to the database as your "queue", each record of which has the information necessary to perform the process in question.  (The data posted from the page, basically, as well as any other meta-data like the user who queued it and the time it was queued, etc.)  The code on the page would do nothing more than simply insert a record in that table.

Separate from the ASP.NET application you would have a background process (a Windows Service might be best, a scheduled Console Application may work just as well) which periodically checks that table for new records.  When it finds records, it executes the process in question on each one successively.

This allows the web application to still be multi-threaded (which you definitely want) while processing the records in a single thread.